# Suppress WordPress warning of old IE version

Tags: php, wordpress

When I try to login on my WordPress website using IE older than version 9. I get the following warning

> It looks like you're using an insecure version of Internet Explorer. Using an outdated browser makes your computer unsafe. For the best WordPress experience, please update your browser.  Update Internet Explorer or learn how to browse happy.`

How do I suppress this warning?

Comment: #1 - you should NEVER ever ever ever [....] publicly post login information, not even for a testuser, unless you are absolutely sure you've hardened your service to the ultimate extend of the physically possible. #2 - it would be very wise to remove the security problem than to ignore the very legitimate warning about it.

Comment: #2 - Users come to my website having Windows XP up to Windows 10. That is why I need to suppress the warning.

Comment: I can still see the log in details you posted if I click on "edited" and view your edits.

Comment: @henrywright I am suggesting your name to secret service agency.

Comment: @ComputerUser you should delete this question. That's the only way those details will be obliterated.